# Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value [object Object] is not a constructor or null" on SNOWPACK build JS of TDA-API-CLIENT

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror, snowpack

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value [object Object] is not a constructor or null
    at tda-api-client.v2.1.3.js:3245:38
    at createCommonjsModule (tda-api-client.v2.1.3.js:20:5)
    at tda-api-client.v2.1.3.js:3186:21
```

I will be going down the error stack. # 1-3

```
//1.   class StreamDataTDA extends events_1.default { //<--- error occurs at default
   constructor(streamConfig) {(...)}

//2. function createCommonjsModule(fn, basedir, module) {
return module = {
    path: basedir,
    exports: {},
    require: function (path, base) {
        return commonjsRequire(path, (base === undefined || base === null) ? module.path : base);
    }
    }, fn(module, module.exports), module.exports; //<--- error on this line
}

//3. var streamDataTDA = createCommonjsModule(function (module, exports) {
```

Tda-api-client is a npm module that I installed. However, when it came to snowpack it's giving me this error. Is there a config that avoids this "misbuild" by snowpack?

Thank you for your assistance